# how to add memoization to this recursive solution stickers to spell words

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming, memoization

I am trying to solve https://leetcode.com/problems/stickers-to-spell-word/

I have come up with the below recursive solution

```
class Solution {
    public int minStickers(String[] stickers, String target) {
        
        int[] arr = new int[26];
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i <26;++i) {
            arr[i]=0;
        }
        int len = target.length();
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < len; ++i) {
            arr[target.charAt(i)-'a']++;
        }
        
        int lenS= stickers.length;
        Integer ans = cal( stickers, 0,arr, 0,len);
        if(ans==Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            return -1;
        }
        return ans;
    }
    
    public int cal(String[] stickers, int pos, int[] arr, int count, int totalLen) {
        int[] mp = arr.clone();
        int curTotalLen=totalLen;
        int didChange=0;
        if(pos<stickers.length) {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < stickers[pos].length(); ++i) {
                
                 if(mp[stickers[pos].charAt(i)-'a'] > 0) {
                     mp[stickers[pos].charAt(i)-'a']--;
                         --curTotalLen;
       
                    didChange=1;
                 }
            }
            if(curTotalLen<=0) {

                return (count+didChange);
            }
            
            if(didChange==1) {

                return Math.min(cal(stickers,pos,mp,count+didChange,curTotalLen), 
                            cal(stickers,pos+1,arr,count,totalLen));
            }
          
            return  cal(stickers,pos+1,arr,count,totalLen);
        }
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
}
```

I am unable to add memoization to this recursive solution. I know there are a lot of solutions for this question online but I would like to add moemoization tho this particular solution that I could think of.
So what my solution does is at every step it recurses for the current word and next word.
If the current word cannot reduce the count of characters in target then it will not recurse for it else it will recurse for it. (It will always recurse for next sticker until I have exhausted all the stcikers)

Comment: Your code did not pass all tests - some got TLE. Is that why you want to add memo improvement? So where do you get stuck?

Comment: Yes My code gave TLE for some cases hence I want to add memoization in this code

Comment: first I think this question is actually NP-complete so any kind of solution wouldn't have a good time complexity... but I would go in another way for iteration and checking.. how about to compress each sticker to the letters components like you did to the target? and then you can rearrange them and compare them in more optimal way? (hint also for what you can use for memorization)